# Measure theory, maximal functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

Question:
Let $\{a_k\}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers and $1 \leq p < \infty$. Show that there exists a constant $C > 0$ so that
$$\Vert \sum_{k} a_k \chi_{\tilde{B_k}} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C \Vert \sum_{k} a_k \chi_{B_k} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$
where $B_k$ and $\tilde{B_k}$ are balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all $k$ so that $\tilde{B_k} \subset 2B_k$, the ball with same center as $B_k$ and twice its radius.

This is my attempt:
Given any measurable function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, define its maximal function as $f^{\ast}$.
Using the result where $$ \Vert f^{\ast} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C \Vert f \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} $$ for some constant $C > 0$ depending on $n$ and $p$ as well as the converse of Hölder inequality:
$$ \Vert f \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} = \sup\left( \int f g \colon \Vert g \Vert_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)}, \int f g \in  \mathbb{R} \right)$$ where $q$ is the conjugate exponent of $p$. Given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists measurable $g$ so that $\Vert g \Vert_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq 1$ and $\int \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \chi_{\tilde{B_k}} g \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$\Vert \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \chi_{\tilde{B_k}} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} -\epsilon \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \chi_{\tilde{B_k}} |g(x)| dx = \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \int_{\tilde{B_k}}|g(x)| dx.$$

For any $N \in \mathbb{N}$ define
$$F_N = \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \chi_{B_k} $$ we have
$$F_N^{\ast}(x) = \sup \left( \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \frac{|B_k \cap B|}{|B|} \colon B \ni x \right)$$
where $|E|$ denotes the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $E$. Then,
$$\Vert F_N \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \geq\frac{1}{C}  \Vert F_N^{\ast} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\geq \frac{1}{C} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \frac{|B_k \cap B(x,1)|}{|B(x,1)|} |g(x)| dx \geq \frac{1}{C} \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \int_{\tilde{B_k}} |g(x)| \frac{|B_k \cap B(x,1)|}{|B(x,1)|} dx.$$

Is there a lower bound $M$ so that for all $k$, $M \geq \frac{|B_k \cap B(x,1)|}{|B(x,1)|}$ and from here I am able to obtain the following bound
$$\Vert \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \chi_{B_k} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\geq\frac{M}{C}\Vert \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \chi_{\tilde{B_k}} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} -\epsilon$$.

Or is there any simpler way to approach this question?

Comment: where is your $C$ in the beginning ?

Comment: Maybe in the details you could go a tiny bit quicker but I think the main idea is to use the conjugate so I would say no there does not seem to be a magical genius idea...

Comment: @JulesBesson The constant $C$ follows from the strong type estimate [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function

Comment: You did not understand what I meant, your $C$ (or a different letter of your choice) is not written in your proposition at the top

Comment: @JulesBesson yeah I have overlooked it. I have made some edits, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Don't worry, it was clear for me, but congratulations if you did this alone with our indications!

Comment: @JulesBesson I don't think I have solved the question, I am still unable to find the bound for the ratio of the balls that holds for all $k$.

Comment: Maybe refine your work by linking the volume of $B_k$ and $\tilde{B_k}$

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final solution:

For convenience, I will assume that the balls $B_k$ and $\tilde{B_k}$ are have the same centers for all $k$, and I will assume convergence for both integrals.

Claim: Let $g \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $B_i$ be a given ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a constant $C_0 > 0$ independent of $g$ so that $$ \int_{2B_i} |g(x)|\, dx \leq C_0 \int_{B_i} g^\ast(x)\, dx.$$

To prove the above claim, for any $x\in B_i$ we have $x \in 2 B_i$ so
$$g^\ast(x) \geq \frac{1}{|2B_i|} \int_{2B_i} |g(y)|\, dy \implies \int_{B_i} g^\ast(x)\, dx \geq \frac{|B_i|}{|2 B_i|} \int_{2 B_i} |g(y)|\, dy $$ taking $C_0 = 2^n$ we have $2^n \int_{B_i} g^\ast(x)\, dx \geq \int_{2B_i} |g(y)|\, dy$. In particular, we have
$$\int_{\tilde{B_i}} |g(x)|\, dx \leq 2^n \int_{B_i} g^\ast(x)\, dx.$$
This concludes the proof of the claim.

Next, by monotone convergence theorem and continuity of the function $\varphi(x) = x^{1/p}$ we have
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \Vert \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \chi_{B_k} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} = \Vert \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \chi_{B_k} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}, \quad \lim_{N \to \infty} \Vert \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \chi_{\tilde{B_k}} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} = \Vert \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \chi_{\tilde{B_k}} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$ Given any $N \in \mathbb{N}, \epsilon > 0$, there exists $g_0 \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that $\Vert g_0 \Vert_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq 1$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g_0(x)|\sum_{k=1}^N a_k \chi_{\tilde{B_k}}(x)\, dx < \infty $
and
\begin{align}
 \Vert \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \chi_{\tilde{B_i}} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} - \epsilon &< \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g_0(x)| \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \chi_{2 B_i}(x)\, dx\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \int_{\tilde{B_i}}|g_0(x)|\, dx\\
&\leq C_0 \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \int_{B_i} g_0^\ast(x)\, dx\\
&= C_0 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \chi_{B_i}(x)g_0^\ast(x)\, dx\\
&\leq \frac{C_0}{A} \Vert \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \chi_{B_i} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}
\end{align}
where $A>0$ is the constant dependent on $p$ but independent of $g_0$ in the strong estimate for maximal function so that $$\Vert g_0^\ast \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq A \Vert g_0 \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} $$ Given that the constants $A>0, C_1>0$ are independent of $N$ and $g_0$ we have
$$\Vert\sum_{i=1}^N a_i \chi_{\tilde{B_i}} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq \epsilon + \frac{C_0}{A}\Vert \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \chi_{B_i} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$ So, taking $N \to \infty$ and allowing $\epsilon > 0$ to be arbitary small, we have
$$\Vert\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i \chi_{\tilde{B_i}} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq \frac{C_0}{A}\Vert \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i \chi_{B_i} \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} $$.

Please do let me know if there are any gaps in my proof. Thank you!